# Sample code to consume resume rest API from Xamarin Storyboard ViewController

Tags: xamarin

Does anyone have sample code to consume RFest API from Xamarin Storyboard Viewcontroller. I have to use a POST method with authentication. I always get timeout error.

Comment: Code that you are currently using?

Answer (score 0):

here is my sample code

```
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Test1", "Pw1232");

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

            string apiResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
            new UIAlertView("Test API", apiResponse, null, "cancel", null);
        }
```